# How to iterate to calculate a set of values in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I am trying to create a new column "roc_30d" using another column "rand_price". The new column is essentially rate of change 30 days. The formula would be (current price - price 30 periods ago) / (price 30 periods ago).

I've tried to iterate over "rand_price" in order to calculate the values of the new column. However, to no avail. Would appreciate it greatly for any advice!

```
for i in df['rand_price']:
    results = (i-(i-30) / (i-30))
    df['roc_30d'] = results
```

In the end, variables i and results has only 1 nan value. Ideally I want the new column to look at the attached png.

Comment: is your this formula correct? `(i-(i-30) / (i-30))`. What is `(i-30)`

Comment: Edit your question to include the `dtypes` for the DataFrame and format the code blocks properly. And let us know where the dates are contiguous https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
i-(i-30) / (i-30)
```

This is algebraically equivalent to `i-1`.  You have a couple of problems:

1. You subtract 30 from the current price.  What you say you want is to get the price from 30 days ago.  To do that, you need to iterate through *rows*, not the values in one column, so that you have the row number.  Subtract 30 from the row number, and use that to locate the value from 30 days previously.
2. Your algebra is wrong.  The formula for a rate is the difference in values divided by the time period.  You divided a quantity by itself, and then subtracted that from the current price.  Instead, try ...

... this ...

```
( [current_value] - [30_day_old_value] ) / 30
```

You may want to work through a tutorial on PANDAS data frames to learn the ways of accessing a particular value with subscripts and the `loc` and `iloc` capabilities.

Comment: Hi there, my apologies as I am new to python. So what you're saying is iterate through the rows and using the index to minus 30, then use the iloc to get the value of 30 days ago? Many thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas DataFrames are not designed for iteration; they are designed for vectorized computation:

```
df['roc_30d'] = df['rand_price'].apply(lambda x: x - (x-30) / (x-30))
```

Note, however, that the formula specified evaluates to (x - 1), so I suspect that you need to work on that.  (@Prune also has an answer that addresses this, so I won't belabor the point.)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for clarifying on that! Will have to do more research on how to get the value n periods ago before I do the computation

Comment: There's a LAG functionality that can help you access the value n periods ago.  But if your time series has gaps (e.g. no data for weekends), "30 periods prior" will not be the same as "30 calendar days prior."

Comment: I figured out how to do the following calculation. I set a column that displays the 30 day lag using the df.shift function onto a new column. Then use those 2 columns to create the column "roc" for the calculation. And yes, noted regarding the calendar days. I've then added weekends and use a ffill for the missing values :)